# Appropriate use of database index?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I'm using SQL database in my application. I  wanted to increase the speed at which search queries are run in my application. So, naturally, I did some research about database index. There are a lot of useful posts in SO about database indexes but these posts put me in a dilemma.
Here is why:

- It is generally good practice to introduce database index in a table if you perform a lot of searching queries in that table.
- It is bad practice to introduce database index in a table if you perform a lot of insert and update queries in that table.

So my question is, Should I index this table so that my searching operations become faster? Or should I find another way to make searching more efficient?
In the concerned table, relatively more insert operations are performed in comparison to search operations. About 10 times as much. But, the search operation is also slow and I do want to increase the speed of search operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the real answer to this, is "it depends".

Which fields are you searching on?  For example, if a user's search query should look in the fields for first name, last name, email address, phone number, zip code, etc... it's perhaps not sensible to index every field, nor would it help much.

How many records do you have? In general, the bigger the table, the slower the search without an index, but the longer an insert/update will take with an index.

How often do users search?  Is it frequent - for example every 5 minutes, or a couple of times a day?

When it comes to indexing, cardinaility is also important. Cardinality refers to the uniqueness of data contained in a column. A low cardinality might not be worth indexing. Think of a boolean field which can be either true or false, and 90% of your records are set to true, and most of the time you query this field for true values. Indexing this field is most likely pointless.

Typically most database engines can only use one index when scanning a table. If you are querying multiple columns then it's worth considering whether an index on one of those columns is more appropriate than another. For example, if you query all products with a Color ID of 2, and a Category ID of 100, it might be that Category ID has a much higher cardinality and is therefore more suitable for indexing than Color ID.

You are right to ask the question, because people sometimes blindly index any field, which will increase the size of the database and hurt insert/update performance. If it were me, and I wanted to search regularly on a particular field, I would most likely index it if the `select` performance was poor without the index.

Comment: I was planning on indexing just one field 'name'. And there is not much uniqueness to the data so a search query has to search all the data in the table. The number of data in the table is also pretty huge. These factors might be a clear sign to introduce indexing. But on the other hand, the frequency of insertion is much higher than retrieval, almost too high. But another factor to consider is that users don't deal with insertions, they only deal with retrievals, so indexing the table to make their life easy would be practical. So I'm still pretty indecisive.

Comment: Try indexing it, and measure the performance afterwards of both the search queries and the insert queries. It might be that the search queries vastly improve, and the insert queries aren't affected too much. I'm assuming `name` is a string, in which case you'd perhaps want to query it either by exact match, or with `name LIKE "smith%"` and not `name LIKE "%smith%"` (I don't believe the latter would use the index)

Comment: Sure, I'll give this a try.

Comment: Index(es) should not slow down insert/update speed much when the table is "bigger".  If relevant, a "composite" `INDEX(color_id, category_id)` could be much better than individual indexes.

Comment: @AadeshDhakal - Help the users; don't worry about your backend stuff.  That is _do_ add indexes; be decisive about this!

Comment: Indexed the table and its much faster now, and no problems related to update/insert operations. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified what kind of data you have.  If there are distinctive keywords that are easily put in a column -- Vehicle make and model, for example -- then index(es) are likely to be very useful.

If you are Amazon, with gobs of different stuff and gobs of different conventions on spelling you have two other problems.

For lots of random words for dress style, model number, chassis style, subdivision name, etc, throw the info in a `TEXT` column and use a `FULLTEXT` index together with `MATCH...AGAINST` -- it will be fast.  But it has some limitations.  For example, `Ford F150` works nicely, but `Ford F-150` will be hard to search for.

Avoid `LIKE '%foo%'`; the leading wildcard prevents use of any index.

Make the indexes for the users; don't worry about the inserts/updates.

(And I agree with most of what MrCarrot says.)

If you provide the type of data involved, I will be more specific on recommendations.